# Enterprise 2014 Bill Payment Query cannot find bill when bill is present in company file

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

Bill payment add cannot find matching bill in Enteprise 14 and the bill does exist for the customer.  Could it have something to do with the length of the bill number?  Please see XML below.

```
<OUTGOING>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><!DOCTYPE QBXML PUBLIC '-//INTUIT//DTD QBXML QBD 12.0//EN' ><QBXML><QBXMLMsgsRq onError = "continueOnError"><BillQueryRq><RefNumberRangeFilter><FromRefNumber>February Publisher P</FromRefNumber><ToRefNumber>February Publisher P</ToRefNumber></RefNumberRangeFilter><PaidStatus>NotPaidOnly</PaidStatus></BillQueryRq></QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>
</OUTGOING>
<RETURNS>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRs>
<BillQueryRs statusCode="1" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="A query request did not find a matching object in QuickBooks" />
</QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>

</RETURNS>
```

Comment: If you're trying to do a BillPaymentAdd, then why does your example show you doing a BillQuery?   You're not doing the right type of request. If you want to do a BillPaymentAdd, then do a BillPaymentAdd, not a BillQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get this to work either. It appears to be a bug in the Bill Query ref number range filter. The query works OK if the ref number range filter is removed.

The filter also works if you use (SOF cuts of part of the answer)

StartsWithFebruary Publisher         P